# Parallel one dimensional array

Tags: c++

I need to create a parallel array one dimensional array.  The first array is string, and the second array is integer.  We haven't really covered strings yet, only char arrays.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  It should look something like this:

```
Enter a student name: Sue
Enter a student name: Harry
Enter a student name: Mark
Enter a student name: Larry
Enter a student name: Carrie

Enter Sue's age: 20
Enter Harry's age: 22
Enter Mark's age: 18
Enter Larry's age: 32
Enter Carrie's age: 29

Sue 20
Harry 22
Mark 18
Larry 32
Carrie 29
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You're really going to have to be more specific than that. Also if you could show us some code that you've attempted that doesn't work we can help you figure out where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: Are you using arrays or STL containers?

Comment: I know how you initialize the second array: int age[5] = {0};  I do not, however, know how to initialize the string array.

Comment: You don't have to initialize it in this case, you only have to declare it. If you declare `int age[5];`, that is sufficient, since the values will be overwritten anyway during the prompting. See http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html for examples.

Comment: @KasaundraScott Also, strings have a default constructor.  An uninitialized array of strings will always be an array of empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, regardless of dimension, can only store 1 type.

You have many options to consider when choosing how you will store this data.
I recommend using STL containers whenever possible, but I do not know the full requirements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

static const size_t SIZE = 10;

struct Student{
  std::string str;
  int i;
};

int main() {

    //example using two arrays for each of the types:

    std::string names[SIZE];
    int ages[SIZE];

    //1 dimensional array examples:

    //C++ std array of paired type
    std::array<std::pair<std::string,int>,SIZE> students1;

    //C++ std array of struct data
    std::array<Student,SIZE> students2;

    //C style array of paired type
    std::pair<std::string,int> students3[SIZE];

    //C style array of struct data
    Student students4[SIZE];

    //vector examples:

    //use a vector to allow dynamic sizes
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> students5;
    std::vector<Student> students6;


}
```